# When does this partial differential equation system have solutions?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, vector-fields

For $P,Q,R:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be three smooth variable functions.

Consider the partial differential equation system
$$\begin{cases}R_y-Q_z=y\\P_z-R_x=x\\Q_x-P_y=f(x,y,z)\end{cases}$$
where 
$$R_y:=\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}$$

For what smooth functions $f(x,y,z)$, the above equation system has solutions?

Moreover, the solution is **unique** or not (up to a field of zero curl)?

---

My attempt:

From the first two equation, we have 
$$Q=\int_0^z R_y ~dt -yz+r(x,y)$$
and 
$$P=\int_0^z R_x ~dt +xz+s(x,y)$$
Hence we have
$$Q_x-P_y=r_x-s_y+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_0^z R_y ~dt -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_0^z R_x ~dt=r_x-s_y.$$

So what all I obtain is that $f$ should be in the form $r_x-s_y$ for some $r$ and $s$.

Comment: @yanko You are right. I will edit my post.

Comment: Interesting problem - please explain what you have done so far. Have you seen a similar problem? Do you have a solution for a special case e.g. when $f(x,y,z) = z$ ?

Comment: The solution can only only unique up to a field of [zero curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)). Searching for "vector field with prescribed curl" is a good start.

Comment: @Alex Thank you and I have edited the post.

Comment: @HansEngler I have added what I have done so far. I have not seen a similar problem so far...